# unable to use openstack due to instance not building

Tags: openstack, devstack

I am new to devstack (openstack). 
I am having some problems getting the an instance to start up.
Here is a screenshot of the issue. The local.conf is also in code form down there.

[image]

```
    [[local|localrc]]
ADMIN_PASSWORD=randomadminpassword
DATABASE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
RABBIT_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
SERVICE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
HOST_IP=192.168.1.100
SERVICE_HOST=$HOST_IP
LOGFILE=/opt/stack/logs/stack.sh.log
SCREEN_LOGDIR=/opt/stack/logs/screen
OS_AUTH_URL=http://$SERVICE_HOST:5000/v3.0
DOWNLOAD_DEFAULT_IMAGES=False
IMAGE_URLS="https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/xenial/current/xenial-server-cloudimg-s390x-disk1.img
```

Comment: Could you please include some specific errors? On the web page if you look at the console output (righht click> Inspect> Console) are there JS errors? On the server, is there an error log?

Comment: @mike, Somehow i got it to work but i am now having a problem with creating an instance. i updated the question with a new image if you could look at it for me

Comment: It's saying that it can't find a (free) nova-compute.

Comment: @eandersson how could i fix this problem, or possibly debug it?

Comment: Start with checking to see if you have nova-compute running on your system. If not you would need to install nova-compute.